# Generic method does not know that the type has a specific method

Tags: c#, generics

This does not compile:

```
public ICollection<T> GetRelated<T>(Widget widget, IEnumerable<T> dbSet) where T : class
{
    return dbSet.Where(x => x.WidgetId == widget.WidgetId).ToList();
}
```

The red squiggly is at `x.WidgetId` and the error is

> Cannot resolve symbol 'WidgetId'.

All of the types I'll be using with this will be classes that have a `WidgetId` property, but the compiler doesn't know that.

I suspect that the only way to get this to work would be to create a base class or an interface that includes the `WidgetId` property (let's call it `IMyBase`), have all of the appropriate classes derive from or implement that, then change this:

```
where T : class
```

to this:

```
where T : IMyBase
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this? Or is this a case of "that's what interfaces are for, so stop whining and start coding"?

Comment: you could try C++ which has duck typing instead of strong typing for generics.  but with C#'s strong typing for generics (Java's too): yes: you need to specify a stronger type for the elements of your enumerable (collection) than simply `class`.

Comment: `object` would meet the `where T: class` constraint but it does not have the `WidgetId` property.

Comment: "that's what interfaces are for, so stop whining and start coding"

Comment: You can do `return dbSet.Where(x => (int)(((dynamic)x).WidgetId) == widget.WidgetId).ToList();` I guess (you may need to change `(int)` to the type your IDs have), but it is ugly and hurts performance, and also lack type-safety (you may get an exception at run-time instead of a compile-time error if you accidentally write a wrong method call), so it is much better to have a common base class or interface as you suggest.

Comment: You could use System.Linq.Dynamic - https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions

Comment: You could check if T has the property/method, then cast the object to that type, but that seems a little excessive when you really want an interface

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
public interface IWidgetId
{
    int WidgetId { get; }
}

public class Widget
{ 
}

public ICollection<T> GetRelated<T>(Widget widget, IEnumerable<T> dbSet) where T : IWidgetId
{
    return dbSet.Where(x => x.WidgetId == widget.WidgetId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You do not _have_ to drop the reference-type constraint `where T : class` because you include the interface; that is you _may_ use `where T : class, IWidgetId` if you want. I mention this because the original question had `where T : class`.

Comment: Your post seems to simply repeat the proposal already present in the question. But it does not appear to answer the question, as posed.

Answer (score -2):

Use [`Enumerable.OfType(TResult)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2).

It will filter out non-widgets but present the remaining widget elements as elements of widget type.

`return dbSet.OfType(Widget).Where(x => ……`

But it is possibly better design to make your `GetRelated` method work only on `ICollection<T> where T: Widget` and use the `OfType<Widget>` filter external to it (i.e., earlier in the pipeline).

Comment: Your answer is based on the elements in the sequence already being a subtype of Widget. The question indicates the elements do not have a common base, only a common property.